# Accesos directos aplicacion Android Shortcuts.xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy personalizando en mi aplicacion de Android, los accesos directos que aparecen al dejar presionado el icono de la aplicacion en el launcher o menu de aplicaciones del dispositivo Android.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cree el archivo Shortcuts y agregue un acceso directo:

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<shortcut
    android:shortcutId="compose"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/notification_icon"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_short_label1"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_long_label1"
    android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/compose_disabled_message1">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.miapp.app"
        android:targetClass="com.miapp.app.main_activity" />
    <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
    <capability-binding android:key="actions.intent.CREATE_MESSAGE" />
</shortcut>
```

En el manifiesto agregue el elemento  como lo indican en la documentacion de Android Developers.

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
               android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
```

Cuando ejecuto la aplicacion en mi dispositivo, la aplicacion muestra correctamente el acceso directo que cree, pero tambien aparece el acceso directo predeterminado, el que tenia antes de crear el acceso directo llamado "informacion", me gustaria poder ocultar lo y mostrar solo el mio.

Lo unico que intente fue no crear ningun shortcut dejarlo vacio, funciona parcialmente, solo oculta el nombre del acceso directo predeterminado que se llamaba "informacion" pero el icono sigue apareciendo.

Si alguien pudiera darme una luz... Gracias de antemano